# C# run function while it returns list of objects

Tags: c#, function, while-loop

My C# function returns 100 list objects at a time. I want to fill a list until this function does not return any lists.

I am trying to do something like this:

```
int lastSelectedId = 0;
while(ReturnListOfCustomers(lastSelectedId).Count > 0)
{
    List<Customers> newCustomers = ReturnListOfCustomers(lastSelectedId);
    CustomerList.Append(newCustomers);
    lastSelectedId  = newCustomers.Last().rowid;
}
```

...but in this case I will have to call `ReturnListOfCustomers` function twice per loop,
can I make it better by calling it one at a time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use do/while

```
int lastSelectedId = 0;
int count;
do 
{
    List<Customers> newCustomers = ReturnListOfCustomers(lastSelectedId);
    count = newCustomers.Count;
    if (count > 0)
    {
        CustomerList.Append(newCustomers);
        lastSelectedId  = newCustomers.Last().rowid;
    }
} while (count > 0);
```

Comment: this code won't work... when newCustomers.Count == 0 you'll get an exception on setting lastSelectedId, need to put a guard condition around it

Comment: On the last item, this is appending an empty list to the CustomerList, then, since newCustomers is empty(count=0) it throws an exception on Last().rowid;

Comment: Oh, since I did not use do while for years, I almost forgot about existence of this keyword :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

In order to remove the two calls per loop, you have to store the result in a variable. I would also refactor your code like this:

```
int lastSelectedId = 0;
List<Customers> newCustomers;

while ((newCustomers = ReturnListOfCustomers(lastSelectedId)).Count > 0)
{
    CustomerList.Append(newCustomers);
    lastSelectedId  = newCustomers.Last().rowid;
}
```

In my opinion at least, I think it looks better than a do-while loop. On the other hand, the do-while loop is probably more quickly readable.

Answer (score 1):

Store the result of the first call in a variable.

```
int lastSelectedId = 0;
var a = ReturnListOfCustomers(lastSelectedId);
while(a.Count > 0)
{
    List<Customers> newCustomers = a;
    CustomerList.Append(newCustomers);
    lastSelectedId  = newCustomers.Last().rowid;
    a = ReturnListOfCustomers(lastSelectedId);
}
```

Comment: count is never being incremented djs.. thi will work best as a do{}while loop.

Comment: The value of Count would be the same as in the original example.  The way he describes it, this would work correctly.  Count will be applied on a new array that is being stored in the same variable, for each iteration of the loop.

Comment: With the do/while, you would check the count twice to maintain the same functionality, if you were doing something other than the append.  You check it to see if you should execute the rest of the loop body, then check again at the loop condition.  I almost always prefer the straight while loop over do/while.

Answer (score 0):

You could reduce the hits by moving the `newCustomers` list outside of the loop, and then updated the list once per loop, after you've completing the appending.

```
int lastSelectedId = 0;
List<Customers> newCustomers = ReturnListOfCustomers(lastSelectedId);
while (newCustomer.Count > 0)
{
    CustomerList.Append(newCustomers);
    lastSelectedId = newCustomers.Last().rowid;
    newCustomers = ReturnListOfCustomers(lastSelectedId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with a simple `for` loop?

```
for ( List<Customer> buffer = ReturnListOfCustomers(highWaterID) ; buffer.Count > 0 ; buffer = ReturnListOfCustomers( buffer[buffer.Count-1].rowid ) )
{
  CustomerList.Append(buffer);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check to see if *your* list grew:

```
 // Assuming CustomerList is a List<Customers> defined and initialized somewhere
 int prevCount = -1;
 int lastSelectedId = 0;
 while (prevCount < CustomerList.Count) {
  prevCount = CustomerList.Count;
  CustomerList.Append(ReturnListOfCustomers(lastSelectedId));

  // Need to check for null return condition
  if (CustomerList.Count > 0) {
    lastSelectedId = CustomerList.Last().rowId;
  }
}
```